# How to create flip book animation effect for any given power point presentation with MS Power Point 2007 with VBA/JQuery/css/JavaScript/Node.js.js

Tags: powerpoint

As there is no easy option available for giving flip book effect to any power point presentation by editing it with the ribbon controls but it is often needed but it is often a compelling necessity though tried to create one with by mixing various options but could not get the desired effect.Will anyone please help to get around this without resorting to higher versions like MS Power Point 2010 or 2013.~~~~

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to do the animation in AfterEffects and export it as a video (PowerPoint 2007 will only accept .wmv files). Note that since it's a video, if any of the slide content changes, you need to export stills back out of PPT and re-render the video in AfterEffects.

Comment: I tried After Effects but could not be installed and it messages me to upgrade to Windows 10 so can I have it done for any power point presentation by converting it to 'HTML 5' automatically and then use 'Turn.js' library and then reconvert it to power point  but how without buying can anyone please guide.I found there are some resources in bashooka site is this going to help